# How to control pitch rotation of an object that is suspended on water

Tags: classical-mechanics, water, buoyancy

I am thinking about designing an underwater vehicle.

It's shape will be cylindrical(12cmx70cm). It will have a pump to pump water into a tank for adjusting density of the vehicle. In that way It will be able to dive and come up. I was planning to use one pump as well one water tank which will be centered on the vehicle's center off mass. Also Its geometrical center will be same as center off mass.

But I need to maintain the vehicles pitch(rotation on Y axis) as it to make vertical angle with gravity. In short I want it to stay in horizontal position as shown in below image. I am quite confused on few things;

1. What happens if the vehicle's center of mass won't be on its geometrical center?
2. How it will be affected by water currents? Can it turn randomly?
3. Should I think about using two pumps and two seperate tanks. As one of them at the end, the other at the begining of the vehicle. For controling the center off mass?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the buoyancy force is nearly constant for all depths, each part of the submarine will feel the same upward buoyancy force regardless of the distribution of weight inside. This means that if the front of the submarine is heavier than the back, then the front will tip forward until the submarine is vertical with the center of mass at the lowest possible position.

Imagine two hollow sphere connected by a rod that both have enough water to maintain a horizontal position at neutral buoyancy. If the right sphere takes on water and the left sphere expels water, the right sphere will sink and the left sphere will rise, creating an overall rotation. This rotation will continue until the heavier sphere is directly below the lighter sphere. The only way to maintain any position is to make sure that the center of mass is at or below the geometric center.

Instead of using two pumps to balance the water taken on, you can design the reservoir so that the whole submarine is naturally balanced. Here's one idea:

[image: Cartoon drawing of a submarine water tank that shallow near the ends of the submarine and deep beneath the center.]

The water reservoir does not have a flat bottom, but one that is lowest towards the center of the submarine and highest near the ends. This way, any water taken on will settle under the geometric center of the submarine. You can experiment with differently shaped reservoirs to achieve different kinds of stability.

As for water currents, the submarine will follow the currents around it, much like a boat on a river will naturally float downstream. If the currents are rotating about a point like a whirlpool, then the submarine will do the same.